# how to find if text strings in one column are in another column?

Tags: r, dplyr, fuzzy-search

Below is the sample data

```
 df1 <- c ("Board of Accountancy", "Board of Economists", "Board of Medicine"
 df2 <- c ("State Board of Accountancy", "The State Board of Economists", "State Board of Law")
```

the task at hand is two fold. First, to search df2 for the text strings found in df1. If it is not found in df1 then leave it alone and come to an end result such as this. This is related to a question that I made yesterday but upon closer examination.. my first job is to find if the names in df1 are found in df2.

```
df3: "State Board of Accountancy", "The State Board of Economists", "State Board of Law", "Board of Medicine"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
c(df2, df1[rowSums(sapply(df1, grepl, df2)) < 1])
# [1] "State Board of Accountancy"    "The State Board of Economists" "State Board of Law"            "Board of Medicine"            
df3
# [1] "State Board of Accountancy"    "The State Board of Economists" "State Board of Law"            "Board of Medicine"
```

Walk-through:

- `grepl` by itself accepts only a single pattern, so we need to iterate over each pattern; we do this with `sapply`
- since that (`sapply`) returns a matrix (each pattern against all of `df2`), we need to find if anything on a row (each `df1`) is a match; we do this with `rowSums(.) < 1` (aka `== 0`), meaning that nothing matched; by subsetting `df1[..]` on this, we get `df1` where no matches were found

---

Corrected data:

```r
df1 <- c("Board of Accountancy", "Board of Economists", "Board of Medicine")
df2 <- c("State Board of Accountancy", "The State Board of Economists", "State Board of Law")
df3 <- c("State Board of Accountancy", "The State Board of Economists", "State Board of Law", "Board of Medicine")
```

Comment: would this change if I made df1 and df2 into data frames?

Comment: yes, you can't `grepl` a frame, but if it's single columns of each frame, then `c(df2$col2, df1$col1[rowSums(sapply(df1$col1, grepl, df2$col2)) < 1])` should still work